# Xaml Binding to object

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i have the follwing class

```
    public class Noticia
{
    public string texto { get; set; }
    public string titulo { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Imagem img { get; set; }

}
```

that contains a property of the type Imagem

```
    public class Imagem
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public string page { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }

}
```

I then have another class to create a list of items of the first class

```
public class NoticiasDB
    {
        public List<Noticia> listaNoticias { get; set; }

        public NoticiasDB()
        {
            Noticia not1 = new Noticia() { titulo = "Noticia 1", texto = "lalala", id = 1 };
            Noticia not2 = new Noticia() { titulo = "Noticia 1", texto = "lalala.", id = 2 };
            Noticia not3 = new Noticia() { titulo = "Noticia 1", texto = "lalala.", id = 3 };
            Noticia not4 = new Noticia() { titulo = "Noticia 1", texto = "lalala", id = 4 };
            Noticia not5 = new Noticia() { titulo = "Noticia 1", texto = "lalala.", id = 5 };
            not1.img = new Imagem() { path = "Assets/pipa.png", page = "Noticias", id = 1 };
            not2.img = new Imagem() { path = "Assets/midia.png", page = "Noticias", id = 2 };
            not3.img = new Imagem() { path = "Assets/pipa.png", page = "Noticias", id = 3 };
            not4.img = new Imagem() { path = "Assets/midia.png", page = "Noticias", id = 4 };
            not5.img = new Imagem() { path = "Assets/pipa.png", page = "Noticias", id = 5 };


            listaNoticias = new List<Noticia>();

            listaNoticias.Add(not1);
            listaNoticias.Add(not2);
            listaNoticias.Add(not3);
            listaNoticias.Add(not4);
            listaNoticias.Add(not5);
        }

    }
```

So my question is how do i do a Binding on a  element that can get the path inside the image from my list of items

i tried something like this , but it appears its not that simple

```
<Image Name="NewsImg" Source="{Binding img.path}" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use BitmapImage to bind Source of image. it works for me. just change few things in your code.

```
public class Imagem
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public string page { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage ImageSource{get;set;}
}

not1.img = new Imagem() { path = "Assets/pipa.png", page = "Noticias", id = 1 , ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/pipa.png",UriKind.Relative)) };

<Image Name="NewsImg" Source="{Binding img.ImageSource}" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Inheritance

Make  Imagem as the base class and as its child

like this

```
public class Noticia : Imagem
{
    public string texto { get; set; }
    public string titulo { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Imagem img { get; set; }
}
```